# Negative points

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

This piss me off! I answer a question and I got 2 up votes.

First I got 4 points for 1st up vote and then I g0t even -2 points for second up vote.

And moderator is ignoring me. I flag the answer and nothing. He said that I reach reputation cap. Ok, but you don't get minus points on reputation cap.

And there is second thing. How come that some people can have higher rep. cap then other?

Comment: Doesn't look like that to me. When I look at your reputation tab, I see only a "+2" for the first upvote, no later reputation change.

Comment: The reputation cap limits reputation gained _through upvotes_ to 200 per day. It doesn't affect reputation gained by getting one's answer accepted or via bounties.

Comment: It reads like "boo-hoo" to me. You can't even be arsed to type properly. "g0t"? Seriously? Calm down and revise three times before clicking "post question" (or post anything, really).

Comment: So you want to say that I'm mad and that I don't know what I saw?

Comment: Could you check what it says in your achievements?

Comment: Nothing...........

Comment: @quid: The Achievements bar is not as immediate as one could think. As long as the day is active, it is feasible that a user would post something that would result in a -1000 points (e.g. something so horrible that 500 people downvote and nobody deletes). So there is no point in advancing that before the day is out.

Comment: @ChristianF He is simply suggesting that you calm  down; wait for answers, revise three times before clicking "post question".  Because you wrote this post and submitted it at a time you felt angry, upset, felt you had suffered a great injustice, and your post shows it.  And it turns out, there is a logical explanation for it all, and that the same policy that applies to you applies to us all.  Now that you've received a calm, non-emotional explanation, you might be feeling a bit foolish for jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @Asaf we may be talking at crossed purposes. I am talking about the dropdown menu in the topabar called "Recent achievements."

Comment: @ChristianF what do you mean by "nothing" There ought to be some entries. What are the last few? (If it is truly empty that's a major bug. Note I am talking up the menu you get when you click the icon in the topbar.)

Comment: @quid: Ah, I see. I was thinking about "progress towards..." badges related to reputation caps.

Comment: That's good as it appears to be the correct global count (200 the max form votes + the two acceptts). To reconstruct what exactly happened will be near impossible. It does happen that the counter does strange things (especially related to deletion and undone votes), but there are "resets" sometimes, so things get straighten out soon.

Comment: Christian, you might make a screen capture (your reputation page on Main) and post in your question. You appear to be seeing something different from what others see. I put such an image in an answer, just for comparison. For example, I see a downvote listed

Comment: The level of your activity is quite impressive, but don't you think 2 points is not really worth getting upset about? This site's reputation system is not perfect (nothing ever is), it's your work that counts

Comment: BTW you can check your reputation also on this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation I have very vague recollection that it was mentioned somewhere that this one should be more reliable than what is shown in the profile, but I am not entirely sure about it. (Maybe somebody else remembers and can you direct to the documentation related to this.)

Answer (score 6):

You never get -2 for the up-vote.  But you might get a down-vote, though I do not believe this was what happened in your case.

But for completeness, the issue is this: at 200 points via votes  you are capped, as I think you know, and upvotes after that do not count.

If you then get a downvote you drop to 198, even if you have plenty surplus votes, the earlier surplus downvotes do not compensate this.

However, if you get a another upvoote after the downvote it will count again.
See this answer [Why do the up-votes after reaching daily rep cap not contribute to compensate the subsequent down-votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160120/why-do-the-up-votes-after-reaching-daily-rep-cap-not-contribute-to-compensate-th/160121#160121)

Regarding why some seem to have a higher cap, this is due to the fact, as explained by Daniel, that not all points one can gain are capped, points from acceptance and bounties are exempt from the repcap.

Thus if you have 20 upvotes and two accepts, you'd get 230 for example (ignoring other events).

What you precisely saw is hard to tell, but it could be explained by the fact that you [deleted an answer too](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2617794/). This influences your score as all votes from it are discarded, yet this might not update instantly. When the delete of this answer kicks in, you gain 2 points, but in turn the value assigned to your last vote would decrease, as it now only took 2 to get too 200, not 4 as when that answer was around.

Answer (score 2):

no idea what ..............................

[image]

Comment: I see something else. I see +232 for today, which is weird, and so might OP. I think due to some deletes and undone votes the counter got confused. Usually it will be back to normal after a while.

Comment: @quid right. It might be good if the OP posts a similar image in his question, those who are involved could compare that to what each is seeing. I know from occasional conversations about unreadable questions on Main that an OP can sometimes be seeing something that has no resemblance to what I see.

Comment: Yes that is how it looks now. At the time of last up vote on this picture it wrote +4 and not +2. Then I got' another up vote and then it decreased by 2.  After that the answer was excepted and after that one up vote was removed.

Comment: @ChristianF all I had to do was look at your profile, then press the "PrintScreen" button on my keyboard. It then asked me if I wanted to save the image, i said yes, and it was saved to a folder called "Pictures" with a name Screenshot from___.png . I had no difficulty pasting that into an answer window here. Suggest you learn how to make some similar screen capture. If you had taken a capture of your reputation, right when you first noticed a problem, and included that in your question above, everyone would have known what you were talking about.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Anyway now stands 231 points today but the total sum is unchanged. Ah, yesterday sum has decreased, it is now 194, of course.